# running sas program for multiple parameters in loop

Tags: sas, export

Very new to sas, need to perform export procedure for many datasets called data1, data2, data3 ... data10.
Is there a way to operationalize this? I've tried the following without success

```
LIBNAME input '/home/.../input';

LIBNAME output '/home/.../output';

%macro anynumber(number);

proc export data=input.data&number file="/home/.../output/data&number..dta" dbms=dta replace;
run;    
    
%mend;


do i = 1 to 10;

   %anynumber(i)

end;

run;
```

Comment: You're looking for call execute here instead.

Answer (score 0):

CALL EXECUTE is the recommended option but a macro loop is also a good option here.
You could loop it within the same macro as well. All options are illustrated below.

Usually when I see this type of coding though, my first thought is that someone isn't familiar with BY group processing.

```
data demo;
   do i=1 to 10;
        *make sure this string matches macro call;
        str = catt('%anynumber(', i, ');');
        *write records to log to check;
        put str;
        call execute(str);
   end;
run;
```

Another option is a macro loop itself.

```
%macro loop_export(numLoops=10);

  %do i=1 %to &numLoops;
      %anywhere(&i);
   %end;

%mend;

%loop_export(numLoops=10);
```

Putting them together:

```
%macro anynumber(number);
%do i=1 %to &number;
    proc export data=input.data&number file="/home/.../output/data&i..dta" dbms=dta 
   replace;
   run;  
 %end;  
    
%mend;

*will export all 10;
%anyNumber(10);
```

Comment: Thank you. The last option worked perfectly!